# Make unit test pass only when callback is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to unit test a bit of code to make sure that a callback is invoked, but it seems that even without an "Assert"-call in the method it will pass. Consider the code example below:

```
public void Show_ShowSomeAdFormat_CallbackShouldBeInvoked()
{
    AdManager adManager = new AdManager();

    adManager.Show<VideoTestAdFormat>((response) =>
    {
        //Assert.Pass(); <--- With or without this, the test will pass. 
        //I need it to only pass if it reaches this. How is it done?
    });
}
```

If you read the comments I think you will understand what I am after.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a captured `bool`.

```
public void Show_ShowSomeAdFormat_CallbackShouldBeInvoked()
{
    AdManager adManager = new AdManager();
    bool callbackInvoked = false;
    adManager.Show<VideoTestAdFormat>((response) => callbackInvoked = true);
    // If the callback is invoked asynchronously,
    // you'll need a way to wait here for Show to complete.
    Assert.IsTrue(callbackInvoked);
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using .NET 4, you might have `Show` return a `Task` that completes when `Show` is done doing work. In earlier .NET versions, you can return a `ManualResetEvent`. "Return" can be a return value, or an overload of `Show` with an `out` parameter.

Comment: Ahh thank you! But isn't it possible that the callback will execute after it actually reaches the "Assert" line? *EDIT: Just tried delaying the callback and it won't work. The Assert will be called before the actual callback.* :(

Comment: If `Show` runs asynchronously, then yes. If that's the case, you either must have some way to wait for `Show` to finish before running the assert, or else you are in the classic problem of testing asynchronous code with a synchronous test. For that, you could use a `Thread.Sleep`, but how long a wait is long enough... The world may never know.

Comment: Ahh okay! Well in the test-scenario it will actually be synchronous but that may not always be the case. Thank you for clarifying (maybe make mention of it in the answer).